# Enviroment variable resolution on Azure webjob running locally

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I'm migrating an azure function to web job doing to the time it takes.

The old code before was using `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CosmosDbAccountEndpoint");` and it was reading from local.settings.json but as I've read the Webjob is a console app so it should get those values from app settings. but how do I use when deployed the Environment variables present in the Azure portal?

I've looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started

and here it says to create appsettings.json for the connection string but I don't understand how to get the variables

Any suggestion?

Here's my program.cs

```
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information

using AzFunctions.SerilogEnrichers;
using AzFunctions.Services;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Extensions.Logging;


var builder = new HostBuilder();

builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
{
    IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json", true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables("TTG_")
        .Build();

    services.AddScoped<xxx>();
    services.AddHttpClient("xxx", (client) =>
    {
        var basePath = configuration.GetSection("xxx").GetValue<string>("FHBasePath");

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(basePath);
    });

    services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider>((sp) =>
    {
        //bool.TryParse(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Seq:Enabled"), out bool seqEn);
        //var seqHost = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Seq:ServerUrl");
        //var sqeApiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Seq:ApiKey");

        var logConfiguration = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .Enrich.With<RemoveAzureUselessEventPropertiesEnricher>()
            .Enrich.WithProperty("ApplicationName", "Azure Functions - Fareharbor sync");
            
        //if (seqEn)
        //{
        //    logConfiguration.WriteTo.Seq(seqHost, apiKey: sqeApiKey);
        //}

        Log.Logger = logConfiguration.CreateLogger();
        return new SerilogLoggerProvider(Log.Logger, true);
    });

    services.Configure<xxx>(options => configuration.GetSection("xxx").Bind(options));
    services.Configure<SeqOptions>(options => configuration.GetSection("Seq").Bind(options));
});

builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
    {
        b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
        b.AddHttp();
        b.AddTimers();
    });

builder.ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
    {
        b.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);

        var logConfiguration = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .Enrich.With<RemoveAzureUselessEventPropertiesEnricher>()
            .Enrich.WithProperty("ApplicationName", "Azure Functions - xxx sync");
        //   .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(sp.GetRequiredService<TelemetryClient>(), TelemetryConverter.Traces);
        //if (seqEn)
        //{
        //    logConfiguration.WriteTo.Seq(seqHost, apiKey: sqeApiKey);
        //}


        b.AddSerilog(logConfiguration.CreateLogger());
    })
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(b =>
    {
        IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
            .AddJsonFile(
                $"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json",
                true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables("TTG_")
            .Build();

        b.AddConfiguration(configuration);
    });



var host = builder.Build();

var basePath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("FHBasePath");

await host.RunAsync();
```

```
{
  "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxxcore.windows.net",
  "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
  "TimerSchedule": "0 38 12 * * *",
  "CosmosDbAccountEndpoint": "https://xxx.azure.com:443/",
  "CosmosDbDatabaseName": "xxxx",
  "CosmosDbCollectionName": "item_test",


  "CosmosDbAccountKey": "xxx==",

  "xxx-US": "xxx",
  "xxx-EU": "xxx",
  "Seq:Enabled": "True",

  "xxx": {
    "AccessKey": "xxx",
    "xxx": "https://somesite.com",
    "xxx": "US,EU",
    "Regions": {
      "xxx-US": "xxx",
      "xxx-EU": "xxx"

    },

    "Serilog": {
      "Using": [
        "Serilog.Sinks.Console",
        "Serilog.Sinks.File",
        "Serilog.Sinks.Seq",
        "Serilog.Exceptions",
        "Serilog.Enrichers.CorrelationId"
      ],
      "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
      "WriteTo": [
        {
          "Name": "Console",
          "Args": {
            "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] [{SourceContext}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
          }
        },
        {
          "Name": "File",
          "Args": {
            "path": "%BASEDIR%/Logs/TTG-WebAPI.log",
            "rollingInterval": "Day"
          }
        },
        {
          "Name": "Seq",
          "Args": {
            "serverUrl": "https://xxx.azurewebsites.net"
          }
        }
      ],
      "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId", "WithExceptionDetails", "WithCorrelationId" ],
      "Properties": {
        "ApplicationName": "xxx"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share your `Program.cs`  and older `local.settings.json` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've read the Webjob is a console app so it should get those values from app settings

Yes, to run `Azure WebJobs`, we need to create a `Console App` in `Visual Studio` and run `webjobs` from there.

- In Visual Studio, create a `Console App`.

[image]

- Add a new configuration file with name `appsettings.json`.

[image]

- As you are trying to retrieve `CosmosDbAccountEndpoint`value from your `Azure Functions local.settings.json` file, I will set the value of `CosmosDbAccountEndpoint` in `appsettings.json` file.

***My `appsettings.json` file:***

```cs
{
  "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxxcore.windows.net",  
  "CosmosDbAccountEndpoint": "https://xxx.azure.com:443/",
 
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "xxxDatabase": "Server=tcp:xxxx.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=xxx;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
  }  
}
```

Right click on the `appsettings.json` file => `Properties` , change the `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy if newer`.

***My  `.csproj` file:***

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk;Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="7.0.1" />   
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Properties\Resources.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Settings.job">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

***My `Program.cs` file:***

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
             .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
             .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        var configuration = builder.Build();
        var cosmosDbAccountEndpoint = configuration.GetValue<string>("CosmosDbAccountEndpoint");
        var cosmosDbAccountEndpoint1 = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CosmosDbAccountEndpoint");

        Console.WriteLine($"CosmosDbAccountEndpoint = {cosmosDbAccountEndpoint}");

    }
}
```

> The old code before was using `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CosmosDbAccountEndpoint");`

- To retrieve the Value from `appsettings.json` ,I have used the below code.

```cs
var cosmosDbAccountEndpoint = configuration.GetValue<string>("CosmosDbAccountEndpoint");
```

- To get the value with the below code

```cs
var cosmosDbAccountEndpoint = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CosmosDbAccountEndpoint");
```

we need to set the value in `Debug` => `General` => `Environment variables`.

Right click on the `Project Root folder` => `Properties` => `Debug`, add the variables.

[image]

***Local Output:***

[image]

Deploy the `Console App` to `Azure WebJob`.

[image]

Continue with next steps to Publish the App.

[image]

> how do I use when deployed the Environment variables present in the Azure portal?

Once you deploy the Application, the local `appsettings.json` values will be available in Aure App Settings.

If you want to override the values of local `appsettings.json` file with the settings in Azure Web App, then we need to set the values in Application Settings.

Either you can add it directly in the portal or you can do it from Hosting section from `Visual Studio` after deploying the App.

Here Iam adding in the Visual Studio `Hosting` section.

[image]

[image]

[image]

- We can check the same in Azure Portal `App settings`and  as well as in `KUDU Console`.

***Azure App Settings:***

[image]

***KUDU :***

[image]

***Path to KUDU Console -***  `https://YourAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/Env.cshtml`

Comment: Thanks @harshitha, so I won't use in my application ```Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("something")``` since in webjobs I can use appsettings, difference of azure webfunctions where I had to use the ```Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable``` to get values?

Comment: As I have mentioned above, we can either use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` or `appsettings` to retrieve the values.Same is with Azure Functions.To use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable`, we need to add those in our `Environment variables`.

Comment: Please refer [WebJobs](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/app-service/reference-app-settings.md#environment-variables-and-app-settings-in-azure-app-service) and [Azure Functions](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp.md#environment-variables) for more details.